# Error 500 ( Fatal Error ) using pg_connect() in php

Tags: php, database, postgresql, centos7

im trying to use `pg_connect` to access postgres on another server,,

i did opened the remote access and i can use `bash` to connect to my postgres server ! and i did host all all client_ip/32 trust in config but when im trying to use `pg_connect` i get error 500 !
`pgsql` is also installed and i've checked it with `function_exists('pg_connect')` and i returns true !
my code is :

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=remote_IP port=5432 dbname=myDB user=postgres") or die("Could not connect");
```

i've also tried this and get fatal error 500 again

```
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=remote_IP port=5432 dbname=myDB
 user=another_super_user_i_made password=user_password") or die("Could not connect");
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: What does the error log say the problem is?

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@shaibow.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

@Blake More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That's what it says on the page, but what does the PHP error log say?

Comment: @Blake [28-Sep-2016 11:10:45 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was host blocking issue ! 
my client hosting was not enabling remote access to DB ! 
you should check with your hosting that they can trace your problem

Answer (score 0):

when you are able to connect to a server from one machine on your network, but get a connection timed out issue from another machine, it usually is due to one of a few things.

1) DNS. The machine you are testing from (the "remote access" as you call it) is able to resolve the DNS name and the webserver running your PHP code is not. You can use actual IP address instead of DNS names to test this.

2) Connectivity. Different machines are connected in different ways in a network. If you are able to get to an IP from the "remote access" machine but the web server is having trouble connecting to it (with "connection timed out"), try connecting directly to that web server (using "remote access" like SSH) and see if you can connect manually from there.

If it's not a network related issue it could be an issue with your default PG timeouts. Try setting them manually with the connect string. Specifically, the "connect_timeout" option, like this:

```
$d=pg_connect('host=example.com user=pgsql dbname=postgres connect_timeout=5');
```

Comment: thanks for answer ! but yes ! i've tried using ssh on client and i can use `psql -U myuser -h myIP` and connect to server ! but i get error when im using php !

Comment: I'd also add to make sure that the port is open for postgres, who knows what service / iptables / firewall rules may be running

Comment: Does the IP you're using happen to be "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: also consider "connect_timeout" in the connect string, as mentioned in my answer edit.